# let $x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1$ .Find the minimum and maximum value of

Tags: derivatives

let $x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1$ .Find the minimum and maximum value of
$$(x_1+3x_2+5x_3)\left(x_1+\frac{x_2}{3}+\frac{x_3}{5}\right).$$

I'm confused how to asssume value from ?

please help me and any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x_1+3x_2+5x_3)(x_1+\frac{x_2}{3}+\frac{x_3}{5})=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+\frac{10}{3}x_1x_2+\frac{26}{5}x_1x_3+\frac{226}{15}x_2x_3$$

Every term of this is positive. To get a maximum then, we should essentially consider which has the biggest impact - clearly here that is $x_2$ and $x_3$ (because of the $\frac{226}{15}$). So, we set $x_1=0, x_2=\lambda, x_3=1-\lambda$, and maximise. In this case we get $\lambda=\frac12\to(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0,\frac12,\frac12)$

For the minimum, the exact opposite logic flows, since $x_3$ has the most impact, we set it equal to $0$, whence $x_1=\lambda, x_2=1-\lambda$, and solve for $\lambda=1$, so $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,0,0)$.